# Lookup which list a name is in and return the top value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my sheet, I have 3 named lists.
I want to lookup which list Person4 is in and return the "List2" title.

So far I have this; `=MATCH(TRUE,List4=E39,0)` which is fine and it gives me back the index value of the name.  But I would now need to somehow return List1, List2 or List3.

But further than that, I do not know which list that person will be in.  So ideally I need a formula where I can grab the name of the person I want to look up, have it then scan all three lists, and return the title of the list the person appears in.

I guess I could use VLookup across all lists for a particular match, but how do I then get the title of the list for that match?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an `XMATCH` for each list, and an `IFS` statement to go through the list. Note that `IFS` returns the **first** correct match, and then terminates.

```
=IFS(
NOT(ISNA(XMATCH(A8,A2:A4))),A1,
NOT(ISNA(XMATCH(A8,B2:B3))),B1,
NOT(ISNA(XMATCH(A8,C2:C5))),C1)
```

[image: multi xmatch]

`A8` is the item to lookup.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I mean, not as automated as I would have liked but you know what?  Meh, this works and it works very well.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't have Excel365 available, you can do it with SUMPRODUCT and INDEX:

[image]

My formula in B10 is:

```
=INDEX(A1:E1;1;SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:E5=B9)*COLUMN(A2:E5)))
```

Comment: Nice one! I think this would also work with previous versions of Excel. Both INDEX and SUMPRODUCT are there from Excel 2007 and up. (Also `--` is not necessary as the TRUE/FALSE is turned in to 1/0 when using the `*` operator.

Comment: What if the list element appears twice?

Comment: @JMP No idea. OP did not say anything about that so I did not consider that